# How to tell if multivariable function is odd?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

A question asks to use symmetry to evaluate this double integral:

$$\iint_R {xy\over(1+x^4)}$$

where $R=[-1,1]\times[1,0]$

The solution states that the integrand is odd with respect to $x$, therefore $R_1=[-1,0]\times[1,0]$ and $R_2=[0,1]\times[1,0]$ cancel each other out since they are equal, but opposite, in magnitude.

I understand the procedure of breaking the domain in pieces due to symmetry, but how does one notice that the function was odd in the first place?

Comment: You just do. It's something you get used to after a while. After all, it's usually pretty easy to tell at a glance whether a function is odd.

Comment: The WHOLE POINT of TeX and LaTeX and MathJax is supposed to be sophisticated typesetting.  You don't need crude workarounds.  I changed $[0,1]$x$[0,1]$ to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

It says it is odd "with respect to $x$".  So, plug in $-x$ to get
$$
\frac{(-x)y}{1+(-x)^4}=-\frac{xy}{1+x^4}.
$$